# image appears green after capture OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, webcam-capture

I have this code which captures image from Webcam using OpenCV:

```
#include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main( )
{
    VideoCapture cap(0); // open the default camera
    if(!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
        return -1;

    Mat meter_image;
    cap >> meter_image;

    imwrite("/boneCV-master/img.jpg", meter_image);

    return 0;
}
```

I get following image as output.

[image]

Previously it was working fine. I don't know what is happening. I tried simplest of all codes upon googling but nothing worked. Please let me know what could be wrong with it.

thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

One thing I forgot to mention is that i am working on beagleBone Black. this same piece of codes works great with my mac.

Comment: Sometimes first frame captured is all zero due to some fault in Camera Driver, Try getting further frames.

Comment: @ATulSingh I forgot to mention Beaglebone black in my question. Please check for my edit

Comment: Sorry to say i do not have any idea about this Beaglebone black. 
One thing you can do just debug the OpenCV capture code , Step into this may be you can find something , Good Luck  (Y)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe adding frame checking will be helpful.

```
Mat meter_image;
while(meter_image.empty()){
    cap >> meter_image;
}
```

But there's a risk of infinite loop.

Comment: Check my edit... I forgot to mention BeagleBone Black here

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know this device. I googled a bit and found this [tutorial](http://derekmolloy.ie/beaglebone-images-video-and-opencv/). I guess you use it. If not check it. Maybe you forgot add some option to compilier.